# Java string to query a varbinary(64) column

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

For a unit test, I need to query a MySQL table for a specific value in a varbinary(64) column. The data is loaded from a csv using jooq.

```
VARBIN_VALS,...
0001,...
0002,...
```

I see the value 0001 when I select on the table after loading the test data. I want to find the record with VARBIN_VALS 0001 so I'm trying to construct the bytes array from a java string. I've tried several variations:

```
"0001".getBytes()
"0001".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
"0001".getBytes(Charsets.UTF_16)
```

but nothing is matching. As far as I can tell mysql is using utf8mb4. How to convert a java string to bytes array that would match what jooq did?

Test data loaded with:

```
ContextObject.loadInto(TABLE_A).
loadCSV(SourceFile).fields(...).execute();
```

And the query is:

```
ctx.select(TABLE_A.FIELD_OF_INTEREST).
from(TABLE_A).
where(TABLE_A.VARBIN_FIELD.eq(bytesArray)).
fetch(TABLE_A.FIELD_OF_INTEREST);
```

Comment: For the record, this question was asked also here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13602

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's happening here is: If your column is of some `byte[]` type (e.g. `VARBINARY`), then the `Loader` API will attempt to decode base64 encoded binary data, see https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5858

Among all the binary string representations, this seems to be one of the most popular ones, but it's probably not what you were expecting. You were expecting jOOQ to pass along the `String` directly to the JDBC driver.

A thorough solution for arbitrary string encodings might be implemented in the near future, see: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3221, where you can define explicit `String` to custom type conversion when loading data from CSV (or JSON, etc.)

Until then, I think the problem is clear? For now, you should either:

- Place base64 encoded binary data in your CSV
- Pre-process your CSV and pass the binary data to an `Object[]` or `Record` representation, and load that, instead

Comment: Yep, that was it. I converted the original string "0001" to byte array UTF-8 then a new base64 string. I replaced "0001" with the new base64 string in the csv and it came back from jooq as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
byte[] varBinary = "0001".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Sorry there was a typo. I was only doing getBytes.

Comment: How are you doing the query?

Comment: Added details about loading and the jooq query.

Comment: Add TABLE_A.VARBIN_FIELD and bytesArray to your selected columns list and compare their values, this may help finding problem, of course you should change where clause to have some output.

Comment: @EskandarAbedini When I pull the varbinary value and convert it a string it displays as: "�M5".